# Two-beat riddle - when am I?

Tags: riddle, knowledge

My first was a grandfather,
My second said when to run,
My third was then a scarecrow,
My fourth was there for longest,
My fifth was a father-in-law,
My sixth was like my fourth,
My seventh changed a bit,
My eighth came only once,
My ninth was once obscure,
My tenth was no landlord,
My eleventh was married,
And my twelfth is an idiot.

**Who or what am I?**

Comment: The use of 12 as well as the title "when" makes me think of something to do with a clock or hours.

Comment: @MisterEman22 This comment is quite ironic given the imagery in the title sequence for series 8...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are:

> The Doctor

Explanation:

> There are currently 12 actors who have played the Doctor, and this also fits the title of "when am I?" referring to the Doctor being a Time Lord.  Time Lords also have 2 hearts which would make sense with "Two-beat".

My first was a grandfather,

> The First Doctor, William Hartnell, was known as "grandfather" by Lady Larn.

My second said when to run,

> The Second Doctor, Patrick Troughton, was well known for the phrase "When I say run, *run*!"

My third was then a scarecrow,

> The Third Doctor, Jon Pertwee, played Worzel Gummidge (a scarecrow) in the 1979-1981 series *Worzel Gummidge*.

My fourth was there for longest,

> The Fourth Doctor, Tom Baker, was the Doctor for the longest (around 7 years).

My fifth was a father-in-law,

> The Fifth Doctor, Peter Davison, had a daughter, Georgia Moffett, who married David Tennant, making him the father-in-law of the tenth Doctor

My sixth was like my fourth,

> The Sixth Doctor, Colin Baker, shares the same last name with the fourth Doctor

My seventh changed a bit,

> The Seventh Doctor, Sylvester McCoy, started as a comical character, but later developed a darker nature.

My eighth came only once,

> The Eighth Doctor, Paul McGann, only appeared as the Doctor once

My ninth was once obscure,

> The Ninth Doctor, Christopher Eccleston, also played the role of Jude in the 1996 film of the same name, based on the novel *Jude the Obscure*

My tenth was no landlord,

> The Tenth Doctor, David Tennant, was "no landlord", he was a Tennant (ba dum tsss)

My eleventh was married,

> The Eleventh Doctor, Matt Smith, marries River during the episode *The Wedding of River Song*

And my twelfth is an idiot.

> The Twelfth Doctor, Peter Capaldi. This is referring to the quote, "You know who I am? I... am... an idiot! With a box and a screwdriver."

Comment: Well done! I thought this one wouldn't last long... The clue for Seven is a bit weak, I'm afraid. The _exact_ answer I intended was "the Doctor" (hence the missing noun is incarnation: "my first [incarnation]" etc.)

Comment: Out of interest, what was the giveaway?

Comment: @randal'thor it was actually just dumb luck. I was looking at your profile because of the recent repaying bounties you made (looking at some PSE history while there are no questions I can answer xD), and I happened to see the Matt Smith quote.  It's labeled as (The Eleventh Doctor) and after I read that I immediately related it back to this question. Before now I had enough previous experience of Doctor Who to know that there are multiple Doctors, so I just googled it all up and the pieces started to fall into place

Comment: [And my twelfth is an idiot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m4Xxj3W6RD0) (with a box and a screwdriver) :-D

Comment: Okay as a true doctor who fan, where is the war doctor in this?

Comment: @Wouter Well, if I'd said "my eight-and-a-halfth or something", the answer would have been even more obvious!

Comment: @MisterEman22 BTW, the explanation for First was meant to be that he's introduced via Susan Foreman, his granddaughter.